# How to use regexp_replace to only keep the number after the dollar sign

Tags: sql, regex, database

E.G. `$21,438 (USA) (9 August 2009)`
I want to keep `21438` (without the `,` and as a float)
Thank you so much!

Comment: which database are you using?

Comment: not referring to any specific database. just want to extract the number

Comment: As @nbk said, String functions are a matter of the `DBMS` or the programming language you are using, did you forget to add Tags?

Answer (score 0):

Use `REGEXP_SUBSTR()` to get the number after `$`. Then replace `$` and `,` with empty strings.

```
CAST(REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(column, '\\$[0-9,]+'), '[$,]', '') AS FLOAT)
```